# Why do I get this EJBAccessException when calling @PermitAll method from Managed Bean?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am learning JavaEE with a JSF webapp.
I have a JSF view which is backed by a Managed Bean, which uses a stateless service to process things.

Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TeamBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private TeamApplication teamApplication;

    public void add(){
        teamApplication.createTeam(); // Actually I wanted to call createTeam("name")
    }
}
```

This is my service

```
@Stateless
public class TeamApplication {

    @PermitAll
    public boolean createTeam(String name){
        //do stuff
    }


    public void createTeam(){
        createTeam("name");
    }

}
```

The thing is:
if I call createTeam("Name") I get an EJBAccessException,
but calling createTeam(), which, in turn, calls createTeam("name") works.
Exception I get:

> createTeam(java.lang.String) of bean: TeamApplication is not allowed

Is there any way to be able to call an secure EJB from a managed bean?

btw: I am using wildly 9

btw2: I had to deactivate default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access to be able to use non annotated methods

btw3: createTeam will not be @PermitAll, as soon as I make it work. It will have @RolesAllowed("Role")

Edit:

Looking at the log, I get:

> DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-34) PBOX00282: Failed to
>   instantiate class Database: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Database
>   from [Module "deployment.webapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Some research lead me to my standalone:

```
<security-domain name="my-security" cache-type="no-cache">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module **code="Database"** flag="required">
```

I think the example I used was from wildfly 8.2, and I am using wildfly 9. This may be causing the problem.
I will look for the correct  code value to use.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Security+subsystem+configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.examsmyantra.com/article/119/javaee/form-based-login-authentication-in-javaee7-with-wildfly-and-mysql) and it has an error by configuring the standalone.xml (in the authorisation part). I removed it and it worked.